# Notification Content Extension is not appearing for multiple category name?

Tags: swift3, apple-push-notifications, ios10, unusernotificationcenter, rich-notifications

I have added Custom Remote Notification Content Extension to my project and added multiple Extension categories into the **Notification Content Extension target** `info.plist` file like the following:

[image]

added different types of notification action categories for different notifications into the `AppDelegate`:

```
 func addRichRotificationActions() {
        let confirmAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "ConfirmAction", title: "Confirm", options: [.foreground])
        let cancelAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "CancelAction", title: "Cancel", options: [.destructive])
        let closeAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "CloseAction", title: "Close", options: [.foreground])

        let openTicketCategory = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "OpenTicket", actions: [confirmAction, cancelAction], intentIdentifiers: [], options: [])
        let confirmTicketCategory = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "ConfirmTicket", actions: [closeAction, cancelAction], intentIdentifiers: [], options: [])
        let closeTicketCategory = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "CloseTicket", actions: [], intentIdentifiers: [], options: [])
        let cancelTicketCategory = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "CancelTicket", actions: [], intentIdentifiers: [], options: [])

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setNotificationCategories([openTicketCategory, confirmTicketCategory, closeTicketCategory, cancelTicketCategory])
    }
```

Now I am sending the apns json following way:

For **Open tickets** getting category name as **"OpenTicket"**:

```
[AnyHashable("default"): You have a new ticket, AnyHashable("aps"): {
    alert = "#8556 - New Booking for Mr. Tomas";
    badge = 1;
    category = OpenTicket;
    "mutable-content" = 1;
    sound = default;
}]
```

For **Confirm tickets** getting category name as **"ConfirmTicket"**:

```
[AnyHashable("default"): You have a confirmed ticket, AnyHashable("aps"): {
    alert = "#8556 - Ticket Confirmed for Mr. Tomas";
    badge = 1;
    category = ConfirmTicket;
    "mutable-content" = 1;
    sound = default;
}]
```

and so on.

But unfortunately, I am receiving the default notification with different action buttons rather than the custom notification content extension with different actions. I can't able to figure out the problem. How is it possible to get notification content extension with different actions for remote notification?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just need to make the **UNNotificationExtensionCategory** as an `Array` rather than `String` in the `info.plist` of **Notification Content Extension** target.